# requestAnimationFrame not waiting for the next frame

Tags: javascript, css, rendering, render, requestanimationframe

Thanks for checking in!

So as far as I know (it may be wrong) JavaScript's requestAnimationFrame method works (a little bit) like setTimeout except it doesn't wait for a certain amount of time but for the next frame to be rendered.

This can be used for a lot of things, but what I'm trying to achieve here is a CSS based JavaScript controlled fade effect. 
Here is what the code looks like with explanation:

```
//This line makes the element displayed as block from none
//but at this point it has an opacity value of 0
this.addClass('element__displayed');

//here i am waiting a frame so that the previously added
//display value takes effect
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    //adding opacity: 1 for fade effect
    this.addClass('element__visible');
}.bind(this));
```

My problem here is that even though the element has its css transition set up and I am waiting for the display value to be rendered, I am getting no transition, it just pops in.

(it works if I use setTimeout(..., 1000/60), but setTimeout is a performance bottleneck compared to requestAnimationFrame)

Please don't try to give an alternate solution for a fading effect because the my question is not the effect, but why the animationFrame isn't working!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a demo

Comment: show the css please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zwgsv3ys/1/ - looks just fine

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thats pretty much what i tried and its not working for me in your demo either (latest Chrome) :/

Comment: @kristófbaján on click of the button what is happening in your system - for me it is working in latest chrome

Comment: There is no need to use `requestAnimationFrame` here at all. You can use `visibility` instead of `display`.  [https://jsfiddle.net/46taexkp/](https://jsfiddle.net/46taexkp/)

Comment: @ArunPJohny on click it just pops in without any transition for me

Comment: @DavidDomain please read the whole description before commenting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* requestAnimationFrame is not guaranteed to wait for the next frame.
[Paul Irish writes](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/requestanimationframe-scheduling-for-nerds-9c57f7438ef4)

> Any rAFs queued in your event handlers will be executed in the ​same frame​.
>   Any rAFs queued in a rAF will be executed in the next frame​.

If adapted your demo, it works for me now on Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/ker9zpjs/

I once found this helper which is in my toolbox since then:

```
var nextFrame = function(fn) { raf(function() { raf(fn); }); };
```

But I must confess that my answer is not fully researched, if somebody could find better information, I would also appreciate it.

Comment: `Any rAFs queued in a rAF will be executed in the next frame​.` That appears to be a lie.

Comment: @H.B.: Do you have any references or examples backing this up?

Comment: I had some issue with WebVR, though those might be artifacts from the external device having its own rAF loops. I would have to look into this more deeply, maybe the actual behaviour is not even properly observable using e.g. the Chrome profiler.

Comment: Looks like it probably is just be a profiler artifact and actually everything executes as expected.